# Problem 2-P8 from "PDE" 4th Edition by Fritz John

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please help this problem: To take into account possible round-off errors we assume that instead of (3.13)$\frac{v(x,t+k)-v(x,t)}{k} + c \frac{v(x,t)-v(x-h,t)}{h} = 0$

$v$ satisfies an inequality $\mid v(x,t+k) -(1-\lambda c)v(x,t)-\lambda cv(x-h,t)\mid < \delta$ (1)

Show that for a prescribed $\delta$ and for $K =\frac{1}{2} (c^2\lambda ^2 +\lambda c)sup\mid f^{"}\mid$ we have the estimate $\mid u(x.t)-v(x,t)\mid \leq \frac{Kth}{\lambda}+ \frac{t}{\lambda h} \delta$  assuming that $\lambda c \leq 1 $ holds ans that $v(x,0)= f(x)$ . Find the values for $\lambda$ and $h$ based on this formula that will guarantee the smallest maximum error in computing $u(x,t)$.

This is problem #2 page 8 from "Partial Diefferential Equation" 4th Edition by Fritz John

I know that

$u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$ and $E^{-1}v(x,t)=v(x-h,t)$, $E$ is shift operator
and $\mid u(x,t+k) -(1-\lambda c)u(x,t)-\lambda cu(x-h,t)\mid  \leq Kh^2$ (2)

Then I try to take (2)-(1) and let $w(x,t)=u(x,t)-v(x,t)$ and get

$\mid w(x,t+k) -(1-\lambda c)w(x,t)-\lambda cw(x-h,t)\mid  \leq Kh^2 +\delta$ 
Now I do not know how to do next.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: hmm, I would say replace $v(x,t+k) = ((1-\lambda *c)+\lambda *c*E^{-1})v(x,t)$. given by 3.13 and $v(x-h,t)=E^{-1}(v(x,t))$

Comment: however, the problem asks you to not assume 3.13 and that v satisfies the stated inequality. Let me think about this one more

Comment: This is what I'm thinking, if you follow how he derived the inequality (2) or 3.18 in the book, by using the taylor series twice(on $f(x-ct-ck) & f(x-ct-h)$), and making the appropriate substitutions to obtain the inequality on the right(easy analysis techniques used here like the triangle inequality). Then you should be able to get the answer you are looking for. Also, notice that h can't be too small neither can it be too big, this part of the problem should be very easy to solve, use calculus techniques to do this(take derivative and set it equal to 0, you know the rest)

Comment: You good? I'll write up my solution in a bit if you want, gotta finish putting the pieces together on paper first.

Comment: Yes please. Even first part I can get it when I use inequality triangle for |u(x,t)-v(x,t)| and following the lecture to get it. For second part I am not sure since there are two variables h and lambda. How can I take derivative and set = 0 for two?

Comment: Take partial derivatives(Calc 3 max and min), I'm still working on the first part. I'm at work scribbling on a napkin so it might take me awhile

Comment: When I take partial derivative by lambda and h then set each = 0 there is no solution. What we conclude?

Comment: Lambda can be anything, so just fix it to be any number. it's h that we have to be worried about and the one that actually matters in this case. Just by observation of the expression, h is the only variable that can't be too small or too big.